# Logging functions in bash and stdout

Tags: bash, logging, stdout

I'd like to be able to put log messages in the middle of bash functions, without affecting the output of those very functions.  For example, consider the following functions `log()` and `get_animals()`:

```
# print a log a message
log ()
{
    echo "Log message: $1"
}

get_animals()
{
    log "Fetching animals"
    echo "cat dog mouse"
}

values=`get_animals`
echo $values
```

After which `$values` contains the string `"Log message: Fetching animals cat dog mouse"`.

How should I modify this script so that `"Log message: Fetching animals"` is outputted to the terminal, and `$values` contains `"cat dog mouse"`?

Comment: Here is a comprehensive implementation of logging for bash: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redirect the output to the sdterr error file on file handle 2 using >&2

example :

```
# print a log a message
log ()
{
echo "Log message: $1" >&2
}

get_animals()
{
log "Fetching animals"
echo "cat dog mouse"
}

values=`get_animals`
echo $values
```

the `` only take the output on stdout, not on stderr. The console on the other hand displays both.

If you **really** want the Log message on the stdout you can redirect error back to stdout after assigning to the variable :

```
# print a log a message
log ()
{
    echo "Log message: $1" >&2
}

get_animals()
{
    log "Fetching animals"
    echo "cat dog mouse"
}

values=`get_animals` 2>&1
echo $values
```

Comment: Yes, I know I *could* ... but I don't want to :-) To re-phrase, how can I deal with multiple stdouts in one script? One for the entire script and one for the function being called.

Comment: You cannot, because there are no multiple stdout's there is only 1. The presence of stdout and stderr is actually an old implementation of a pattern to separate payload from monitoring/instrumentation. The only ways to get the log() output to separate it from the payload or mark it so you can remove it afterwards : e.g. `get_animals | grep -v "^Log message:"` . Marking it and removing it is according to me even worse.

Comment: Cool, OK I'll do that. I'd quite hoped I could reserve stderr for error output, and use stdout for logging output. I suppose the problem was between my keyboard and my chair :-)

Comment: It's not possible to use functions to output a result AND to log out texts. Because both use echo.

Answer (score 24):

[choroba's solution to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101327) shows how to use exec to open a new file descriptor.

Translating that solution to this question gives something like:

```
# Open a new file descriptor that redirects to stdout:
exec 3>&1

log ()
{
    echo "Log message: $1" 1>&3
}

get_animals()
{
    log "Fetching animals"
    echo "cat dog mouse"
}

animals=`get_animals`
echo Animals: $animals
```

Executing the above produces:

```
Log message: Fetching animals
Animals: cat dog mouse
```

More information about using I/O redirection and file descriptors in Bash can be found at:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners, section 8.2.3, Redirection and file descriptors](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_03)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, Chapter 20, I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: Why is this solution not the accepted solution? It addresses the exact question the OP had asked.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution

Comment: the redirection could also be to a log file `exec 3>"$logfile"` or to the terminal with `exec 3>/dev/tty`

Answer (score 7):

```
# purpose: to pass msgs and print them to a log file and terminal
#  - with datetime
#  - the type of msg - INFO, ERROR, DEBUG, WARNING
# usage:
# do_log "INFO some info message"
# do_log "ERROR some error message"
# do_log "DEBUG some debug message"
# do_log "WARNING some warning message"
# depts:
#  - PRODUCT_DIR - the root dir of the sfw project
#  - PRODUCT - the name of the software project dir
#  - host_name - the short hostname of the host / container running on
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_log(){

  print_ok() {
      GREEN_COLOR="\033[0;32m"
      DEFAULT="\033[0m"
      echo -e "${GREEN_COLOR} ✔ [OK] ${1:-} ${DEFAULT}"
  }

  print_warning() {
      YELLOW_COLOR="\033[33m"
      DEFAULT="\033[0m"
      echo -e "${YELLOW_COLOR} ⚠ ${1:-} ${DEFAULT}"
  }

   print_info() {
      BLUE_COLOR="\033[0;34m"
      DEFAULT="\033[0m"
      echo -e "${BLUE_COLOR} ℹ ${1:-} ${DEFAULT}"
  }

  print_fail() {
      RED_COLOR="\033[0;31m"
      DEFAULT="\033[0m"
      echo -e "${RED_COLOR} ❌ [NOK] ${1:-}${DEFAULT}"
  }

  type_of_msg=$(echo $*|cut -d" " -f1)
  msg="$(echo $*|cut -d" " -f2-)"
  log_dir="${PRODUCT_DIR:-}/dat/log/bash" ; mkdir -p $log_dir
  log_file="$log_dir/${PRODUCT:-}."$(date "+%Y%m%d")'.log'
  msg=" [$type_of_msg] `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"` [${PRODUCT:-}][@${host_name:-}] [$$] $msg "
  case "$type_of_msg" in
    'FATAL') print_fail "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
    'ERROR') print_fail "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
    'WARNING') print_warning "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
    'INFO') print_info "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
    'OK') print_ok "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
    *) echo "$msg" | tee -a $log_file ;;
  esac

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect log output to the standard error stream:

```
log()
{
    echo 1>&2 "Log message: $1"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to log to stdout, not stderr.