# Bash script global redirection with exec and write to screen

Tags: bash

I have a large bash script and I want to globally redirect all stdout/stderr to a file, *except* some progress indicators such specific echo messages. For example, consider the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

# all stdout and stderr go to out.log
exec &> out.log

special_echo "starting"

# many other commands go here
# which output both the stdout and stderr
# also some special_echo commands in here,
# for example
echo "msg1"
special_echo "middle"
echo "msg2" >&2

special_echo "finished"
```

When it is run the output should be

```
$ ./script
starting
middle
finished
$
```

But, `out.log` should contain

```
msg1
msg2
```

How to implement `special_echo` functionality? I've tried using a file descriptor and echoing to that but can't get it to display on the screen.

Is there a way to achieve this without appending redirection to every line or doing something like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315113)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, using another file descriptor is the way to go:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1
special_echo () {
    echo "$@" >&3
}

exec &> out.log

special_echo "starting"
echo "msg1"
special_echo "middle"
echo "msg2" >&2
special_echo "finished"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I had `exec &> out.log` first and then `exec 3>&1` which now I see was the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of your script save your `stdout` & `stderr` as custom descriptors.

```bash
# all stdout and stderr go to out.log
exec 3>&1 4>&2 &>out.log
```

<sup>you can use `3>/dev/stdout` instead of `3>&1` et cetera, or split it into multiple `exec` redirect lines, if that's more readable to you.</sup>

Then all you need to do is use them

```bash
echo "starting" >&3
echo "msg1"
echo "middle"   >&3
echo "msg2" >&2
echo "finished" >&3
```

<sup>you cant use `>/dev/stdout` because it actually got overridden with `exec`, custom descriptors are necessary.</sup>

The best part about this is that you still have access to the original `stderr`, which you wont with `/dev/tty`

```bash
echo "special error" >&4
```

And you can completely undo your redirection for the rest of the script if that's something you need.

```bash
#restore original
exec >&3 2>&4

echo "this is special now"
```

No functions, no variables, just works.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to /dev/tty, which is the controlling terminal. Works also for input.

Comment: Is it POSIX to redirect to /dev/tty?